# Unable to close SSHD on IPv6 TCP port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-10.04, ipv6

I'm running Ubuntu 10.4 and I've tried disabling IPv6 as I don't currently need it. I rand the following to disable IPv6 and then rebooted my server:

```
echo "#disable ipv6" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

After the reboot I can see that IPv& is disabled by running:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

On running `netstat -antlp` i see that most of the IPv6 applications have closed but SSHd keeps running:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      663/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      663/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      684/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      513/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      605/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      684/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      513/sshd
```

Ho can I close the SSH daemon on port 22 of the IPv6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/questions/465/Configuring+SSH+to+listen+on+IPv6+addresses)

The way to *enable* ipv6 for SSHD is to write a line in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that says `ListenAddress ::`

So I would do the reverse, edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and delete that line.

So your file would have looked like

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

Now you simply want it to say

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

-=EDIT=-

Another way to disable ipv6 is apparently listed on [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-910.html):

> 1. Open a terminal and type the following command (if you don't use Gedit, replace it with your text editor such as Kate, etc).
>
>    `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
> 2. And search for this:
>
>    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`
>
>    Modify it so it looks like this:
>
>    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"`
> 3. Update the GRUB:
>
>    `sudo update-grub2`
>      or
>      `sudo update-grub`
>
>    depending on which version of Grub you are using.

Comment: Hi Mokubai. Both of those lines in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` seem to be commented out by default. Do I simply uncomment the `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` and restart the SSHd?

Comment: I would certainly try that first, it may be that without either of those lines present (i.e. both are commented out) then it defaults to a "built-in" config with both ipv4 and ipv6 enabled.

Comment: Uncommenting that line did it, it seems. Yay! Thank you.

Comment: ..or maybe I spoke too quick. That didn't do it.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but users may still coming here. The commented out lines in the config file are defaults, so if you "simply uncomment" a line but don't change it in any other way, nothing is going to change.

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this page before discovering an answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126793/353061

Reposting:
By default `sshd` uses ipv4 and ipv6.  You can configure the protocol sshd uses through the `AddressFamily` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

For ipv4 & ipv6 (default)

```
AddressFamily any
```

For ipv4 only

```
AddressFamily inet
```

For ipv6 only

```
AddressFamily inet6
```

After you make any changes to `sshd_config` restart `sshd` for the changes to take effect.

In addition here is how you can do it in sed:

```
sed -i 's/^#AddressFamily any/AddressFamily inet/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And restart sshd:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it binds to 0.0.0.0 and ::, but, if IPv6 is disabled on the interface, it will not accept connections on that interface. Did you tried to connect over disabled IPv6 interfaces?